# Validation can not updating value in database

Tags: laravel

I am uses validation for gst and adhar but when its error free i am updating value but value can not updating. I am giving updating code in else part. what is mistake done by me? need a solution. In if part i am checking validation and in else part if error is not coming, i am updating value from table but i can not work.

```php
public function profile_update(Request $req,$id)
{

    $mytime      = Carbon::now();
    $fullname    = $req->input('fullname');
    $email       = $req->input('email');
    $mobile      = $req->input('mobile');
    $gender      = $req->input('gender');
    $gstnumber   = $req->input('gst_number');
    $adharnumber = $req->input('aadhar_number');
    $password    = $req->input('password');
    $cpassword   = $req->input('c_password');
    $updated_at  = $mytime->toDateTimeString();
    $created_at  = $mytime->toDateTimeString();

    $validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
        'email' => 'email|unique:users,email',
        'aadhar_number' => 'unique:users,aadhar_number' ,
        'gst_number' => 'regex:^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$^|unique:users,gst_number'
    ]);
    if($validator->fails()) 
    {
        //dd("hello");
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        //return Redirect::to('/customer')->with('message', 'Register Failed');
        return redirect('/profile')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        if ($req->hasFile('update_image'))
        {
            $image           = $req->file('update_image');
            $filename        = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/images/users_profile/');
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            DB::update(
                'update users set name = ?,email = ?,mobile = ?,image = ?,gender = ?,gst_number=?,aadhar_number=?,password = ?,cpassword = ? where id = ?',
                [$fullname, $email, $mobile, $filename, $gender, $gstnumber, $adharnumber, $password, $cpassword, $id]
            );
        }
        else
        {
            DB::update(
                'update users set name = ?,email = ?,mobile = ?,gender = ?,gst_number=?,aadhar_number=?,password = ?,cpassword = ? where id = ?',
                [$fullname, $email, $mobile, $gender, $gstnumber, $adharnumber, $password, $cpassword, $id]
            );
        }
        return redirect('/profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "gst and adhar"? What do you mean by "can not updating"? Validation should never update anything, that's why it's called validation

Comment: The execution is going inside `if($validator->fails())` or `else` ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz if excution fails it going to if, but not fails it can not go in else part

Comment: @smitapatil are you sure ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes sir only update code can not work but i remove validate ,then it works

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the if else statement

```
$req->validate([
    'email' => 'email|unique:users,email',
        'aadhar_number' => 'unique:users,aadhar_number' ,
        'gst_number' => 'regex:^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$^|unique:users,gst_number'

// continue your update code here

]);
```

Simply do this and it will do the needfull for you 
if your conditions are not met by the values it will return to the previous view and if the conditions are met, it will continue to run the codes.

for updating the data

```
  $data = user::find(id);
  $data->name = $name;
  $data->email = $email;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  //update all the fields 
  $data->save();
```

Comment: hello it works but new value can not update can i share my blade file code?

Comment: hello , i have edited my answer , please do check @smitapatil